# How to change exporting filename in highcharts

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I want to change the filename of files downloaded from Highcharts 2.3.5 export but I am not able to do so. I have tried to change it but wasn't successful. [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/n05f2q0r/1/)

I have tried to change to chart_new_name but it only downloads a file named chart.[required extension (png,jpeg,pdf,svg)].

```
exportChart: function (a, b) {
        var c = this.options.exporting,
            d = this.getSVGSH(l(c.chartOptions, b)),
            a = l(c, a);
        e.post(a.url, {
            filename: a.filename || "chart"+_newname,
            type: a.type,
            width: a.width,
            scale: a.scale || 2,
            svg: d
        })
```

Downloads only chart.[png ,jpg,pdf] but I need it to download chart_newname.[png,jpg,pdf]

Comment: Try this http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/highcharts/Example/Export/Set_file_name_for_export.htm

Comment: also http://jsfiddle.net/0u3jj15u/1/

Answer (score 2):

You should use `exporting.filename` option for this:

```
exporting: {
    filename: 'custom-file-name'
}
```

Live example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emrebolat/3L2n20a8/)